# IIS 7 - URL Rewrite - do I include the http or https protocol in the regex?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

In IIS 7.5 (Win2k8 R2) I'm trying to create a new rule for these requests:

```
http://www.domain.com/userprofile
https://www.domain.com/userprofile
http://domain.com/userprofile
https://domain.com/userprofile
```

rewriting to:

```
http://www.domain.com/users/?username=userprofile
(or whatever the protocol/domain is)
```

The regex that I wrote is:

```
^(http|https)://(www\.domain.com|domain\.com)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]{6,35})
```

and the rewrite is:

```
{R:1}://{R:2}/users/?username={R:3}
```

But this is not working. Is it because I don't need to the protocol? I also added conditions that the request is not a file or directory.

Also, do I need to restart IIS each time I change the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marco was almost right, but here's how what ended up working: (I used the URL Rewrite form in IIS Manager)

Regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-]{6,35})(/?)$
```

Conditions:

```
Not a file
Not a directory
```

This forces the match to start directly after the domain and must be either the first directory, or with no trailing "/". According to the regex, the match must be between 6 and 35 characters, alpha numeric with "-"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to look at the protocol or domain name when you want to rewrite these request. It's not important in your case as you only want to rewrite the path.

The following rule should work:

```
<rule name="Rewrite user profiles">
    <match url="([a-zA-Z0-9-]{6,35})" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/users/?username={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

You don't have to restart IIS when you change the rule. IIS will automatically restart the application pool when web.config is modified and hence reload the rules.

Comment: I think this is too broad of a rule. The entire site breaks, and I think it's because it's rewriting requests to javascript files, etc. I think I need something that takes into consideration the path.

Comment: It depends on how you name your javascript files. But sure, it's a good idea to add that condition that it should not match existing files or directories. I was more focused on that you should not include the domain name and protocol.

Comment: Yes, your answer definitely clued me in... thank you! Your regex pattern was matching things like: http://domain.com/javascript.js and rewriting them.

Comment: Ah mmm, it will match `javascript` of course (not the `.js` part though). Your fixed regex is almost good, but `(/|$)` is not the correct way to match an optionally trailing back slash. Better use `^([a-zA-Z0-9-]{6,35})(/?)$`.